# Moodle plugin development - Is it possible to add html element to course/view.php?id=x from Activity module plugin I'm developing?

Tags: php, moodle

I am developing a plugin for **comments and ratings of resources** in moodle, so I figuered out that it is activity module type of plugin.

My goal is to enable students to rate resources and comment them but i can't find a way to display my star rating on a *`course/view.php?id=x`* page, where x is id of course. So basically, i want my plugin to add something like this:

[image]

I did research on https://docs.moodle.org/dev/NEWMODULE_Documentation, but there are no examples of plugins which add any html elements to the page mentioned above, and i couldnt find a way on my own of accessing course page view from activity module plugin. Is there a way i can achieve that?

My moodle version is 3.01

Comment: Sounds like something that should be a block plugin that should appear on activities that need ratings (or be added at the course level and set to appear on all pages in the course). I've certainly developed similar plugins for customers in the past (but nothing I've been given permission to share the code for).

Comment: Thanks mate, can you please explain me why that should be block plugin ? 
Comments and ratings should appear for every resource on a course, and it would be best if admin wouldn't have to add manually these commens and ratings for every resource. So maybe that would have something to do with settings.php?
Thanks in advance, I would really appreciate if you could explain me this thing about block plugin :)

Comment: Add a block to the course and set it to appear on every page in the course. You can the use $PAGE->cm to detect the resource being viewed.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I'll try it that way :)

Answer (score 1):

After more detailed research, I found out that only way to achieve this is to change core of moodle. Precisely, in mod/resource/lib.php, there's function resource_cm_info_view(cm_info $cm), and $cm has function set_after_link(). So if that function is **enabled**, you can set afterlink. But that afterlink should lead to page on which are displayed comments and ratings for that particular resource. And that can be achieved throuh plugin.

Here are couple of pictures so You can see what i'm talking about: 
[mod/resource/lib.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofcgy.png)
[live moodle platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JqlW.png)

Basically, if moodle community agrees to update moodle just a bit,and add something like

> if (plugin exists) 
>   {
>     enable afterlink function and pass it parameter for comment and rating link
>   }

then it would be possible to create plugin that it is discussed. But that is up to them, and I am not sure if they would agree to such a thing.

So, **short answer to my question is: No, it is not possible.**

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question but might help...

- https://moodle.org/plugins/block_rate_course
- https://github.com/moodle/moodle/tree/master/blocks/comments

Comment: Thank you, I did more serious research with help of some more experienced developer and made some conclusions, I will post them as an answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in moodle/cource/view.php file :

```
<?php
.
.
echo $OUTPUT->header();
?>

<html elemets>

<?php
.
.
echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```